# SQL changing switch based on existent of other record or a logical on another table

Tags: sql, plsql

Here are some test tables and records to help explain my problem:

```
create table table1
(item   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
 type   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
 is_on  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);

create table table2
(item   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
 switch VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
);

insert into table1
values('1', 'a', '0');

insert into table1
values('1', 'a', '0');

insert into table1
values('1', 'b', '0');

insert into table1
values('1', 'b', '0');

insert into table2
values('1', '1');
```

I need a sql or plsql script to switch table1.is_on. Here are the rules:

1. If there are only type 'a' for an item then set type 'a' to on
2. If there are some type 'b' for an item then set type 'b' to on and a to off
3. If the switch on table2 is on for an item reverse the logic and set 'b' to off and 'a' to on

I know how to use the encode statement and I think that could help but I don't really know where to start past that.

Note: This is one small part of a much bigger problem I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 x
   SET is_on =
          (SELECT DECODE ( x.TYPE,  'a', ABS (s_a - NVL (b.switch, 0)),  'b', ABS (s_b - NVL (b.switch, 0)),  x.is_on)
             FROM (  SELECT item, - (SIGN (COUNT (*) - COUNT (DECODE (TYPE, 'a', 1, NULL))) - 1) s_a, SIGN (COUNT (DECODE (TYPE, 'b', 1, NULL))) s_b
                       FROM table1
                   GROUP BY item) a
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.item = b.item
            WHERE a.item = x.item)
```